# What are people using for displaying Image / Media copyright information?

Tags: images

I have tried the 'Image Credit' plugin but it seems flaky (possibly due to interaction with other plugins). What are other people using? The requirement is for each image used to have an associated field for copyright info.

Comment: FWIW I think the real issue is that there is no way to insert links into captions in the media uploader. Please vote for this "Idea" to have that fixed http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/fix-the-caption-system-to-allow-links-inside-captions

Answer (score 1):

You could use the description or caption part of the image editor/uploader and then query that for each image. To clarify what I mean read my the post I wrote at my blog for creating a sideshow in wordpress with titles and captions without using a plugin. I don't know if you're making a slideshow, but if you're not, take out the jquery part and it's essentially the same idea.

http://www.eileencarpenter.net/blog/worpdress-building-a-jquery-slideshow-without-a-plugin

Comment: Thanks. I think the description is the best solution as even though its meant to be a descriptive field for the admin interface, it is rarely used.